# What can I use to do decent content aware image resizing on OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, image-editing

What can I use to do decent content aware image resizing on OS X?

I know that Photoshop and iResizer are supposed to provide this, but first is quire heavy and expensive and the other one seems not to give best results.

Are any other alternatives?

Comment: Creative Cloud subscriptions are quite reasonably priced as an alternative to buying Photoshop. If you need to do anything beyond basic image manipulation, there still is nothing that can compare.

Comment: I agree Photoshop is undefeated, it does a really good job with content aware.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe give [Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com) a shot? The website offers a free demo.

Comment: While an excellent piece of software, Pixelmator does not have any content aware scaling.